# I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error with dynamically allocated arrays for merge sort in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I think I have stared at this long enough to make my eyes roll to the back of my head. I am trying to implement an ascending merge sort using dynamically allocated arrays, and although (I believe) my logic behind the algorithm is correct, I am getting the segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I know that it means somewhere I have a pointer pointing somewhere it shouldn't or vice versa, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Suggestions?

Main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int my_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
  bool sorted = false;

  if( argc != 2)
    {
      printf("Program usage: %s sortname\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }

  // Fill array with random numbers
  initArray(my_array, ARRAY_SIZE);

  // Sort array by chosen algorithm
  if(strcmp(argv[1], "bubble") == 0)
  {
    bubbleSort(my_array, ARRAY_SIZE);
  }
  else if(strcmp(argv[1], "merge") == 0)
    {  
      mergeSort(my_array, ARRAY_SIZE);
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Invalid sort algorithm. Must specifiy 'bubble' or 'merge'\n");
      return 1;
    }

  // Test if array is sorted correctly
  sorted = verifySort(my_array, ARRAY_SIZE);


  if(sorted)
    printf("Congrats! Array is sorted correctly\n");
  else
    printf("*** Error: Array sort algorithm fails verification test ***\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Merge Sort

```
//mergeSort is what I call from main, the array that is passed in is defined as: 
//int my_array[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
//It is filled with random numbers and passed into mergeSort
void mergeSort(int *array_start, int array_size)
{
    printf("Using merge sort algorithm...\n");

    int min = 0;
    int max = array_size-1;

    mergeSortHelper(array_start, min, max);
}

void mergeSortHelper(int *array_start, int min, int max)
{   
    int mid;

    if (min<max)
    {
        mid = (max+min)/2;
        //split into two halves
        mergeSortHelper(array_start, min, mid);     //left half
        mergeSortHelper(array_start, mid+1, max);   //right half
        merge(array_start, min, mid, max);
    }
}

void merge(int *array_start, int min, int mid, int max)
{
    int i, j, k, left, right;

    left = mid - min + 1;
    right = max - mid;

    int *leftArray = calloc(left, sizeof(int));
    int *rightArray = calloc(right, sizeof(int));

    //copy to left temp array
    for(i = 0; i < left; i++)
    {
        leftArray[i] = array_start[min+1];
    }

    //copy to right temp array
    for(j = 0; j < right; j++)
    {
        rightArray[j] = array_start[mid+1+j];
    }

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = min;

    //merge temp arrays 
    while(i < left && j < right)
    {
        if(leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j])
        {
            array_start[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            array_start[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    //copy extra elements back to array
    while (i < left)
    {
        array_start[k] = leftArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < right)
    {
        array_start[k] = rightArray[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    free(leftArray);
    free(rightArray);
}
```

Comment: Did you use valgrind to see where it fails?

Comment: If you're not using malloc or calloc to allocate space for the array being passed in, then it's probably the call to free() at the end that is causing your seg fault, as these arrays are not allocated on the heap and therefore not technically "run time"

Comment: Could you provide the full code (with the `main()` function)? This would help us see wether there's anything wrong with your sorting function or with the arguments you pass to it.

Comment: @RockOnRockOut I am new to C and am using gedit and command line in Ubuntu (which I am also very new to using) and am unfamiliar with valgrind. Will head to Google now! Thanks!

Comment: @Jay I have added main

Comment: @laser_wizard I will try getting rid of the free()

Comment: How many elements do you want in `leftArray` and `rightArray`, and how do you tell `calloc()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (i < left)
{
    array_start[k] = leftArray[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

This looks like an infinite loop to me. There's nothing inside of it that changes the value of `i` or `left`, so eventually `k` or `j` grows large enough to cause the fault.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I accidentally put j instead of i in that function! Just needed another set of eyes to catch the mistake. Thanks again!!